# USB headset no sound during games or playing music, but i can hear on ventrilo

Tags: windows-vista, usb, audio, headset, ventrilo

I currently just bought a new USB headset to replace my old mic. I put everything in order today and i can hear people talk when i'm logged in through Ventrilo, however, i get no game sounds or music playing from anything else. Just only from the Ventrilo people talking i can hear them.

I have the Vista operating system installed. Please help , it's frustrating me lol.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the headset as the default audio device if you want all of your system sounds to come through it.

1. Right-click on speaker icon in system try
2. Select playback devices
3. Find your headset in the list, and click "Set Default"

(These are based off of W7, but I think they're still good for Vista)

Comment: i tried to do this, but when i went to Control Panel > Sound > It came up with a message stating ( C:\Windows\System32\Rundll32.exe "Application Not Found)

So i have no idea what to do now. That is most likely it. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I can't say I do, that looks like a possibly corrupt windows installation. Either it can't find the control panel item or some application you installed replaced it, and then was deleted.

Try opening the run dialog (Win+R, or Start->Run) and try to execute `mmsys.cpl` This should bring up the Playback/Recording dialog. (Again, might've changed between Vista and W7, I'm hoping not)

Comment: You sir are amazing. This did fix my problem. Just did the run option and put it in for Vista, and it popped right back up. Set it to default did a quick reboot and it works. Everything. Game music, ventrilo, and media music. Thanks for the help guys/gals

Answer (score 0):

USB Headset s.cks. I own one for a long time and it gave me soo hard times. First it didn't work at all. On Vista, if I moved the slider a bit, the sound was gone, had to reinstall *all* the usb drivers to get it back and NEVER touch the volume control. Now, Win7 supports it somewhat. Seriously, **NEVER** buy such thing.

In your case, you should check the default devices in Windows, and/or in the application. (And try updating to the latest driver from the manufacturer's website if you didnt do that already.)

Comment: i'm sorry i'm kinda dumb, where do i check for the default devices at ?

Comment: http://noob.hu/2010/06/02/sound.jpg